Why the variable "status" keep unchange?
My code link is here.
I found that the console shows the variable "status" value is "pending" every time, even though I have the following code to set it to a different value.
let suspender = api({
    url: 'https://data.etabus.gov.hk/v1/transport/kmb/route-stop/7/inbound/1',
    method: 'get',
  }).then(
  (r) => {
    console.log("r", r);
    status = 'success';
    result = r.data;
  },
  (e) => {
    status = 'error';
    result = e;
  }
);

Would you tell me what's going on?

because you call .read() which logs status before status is set by the .then() callbacks.

I have moved the function read after the .then callback, but the problem still exists. How can I solve the problem?

See: Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference
